# Implementing a python code to a cython code

Tags: python, anaconda, cython

I have tried to implement the following python script into cython to decrease the running time. I have very little experience with python and/or cython. I tried to use something like the following lines, but did not work. Is it any "easy" ways of running the python script in cython or must I change the entire script?

```
# What I tried:
import time
import pyximport; pyximport.install()
import kandetlykkes

# The python codes:
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw # Importerer biblioteket

# Load image:
input_image = Image.open("beatles.jpg") # Loads an image from the hard drive
input_pixels = input_image.load()

# Box Blur kernel
box_kernel = [[1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9], [1 / 9, 1 / 9, 1 / 9]]

# Select kernel here:
kernel = box_kernel

# Middle of the kernel
offset = len(kernel) // 2

# Creating the output image
output_image = Image.new("RGB", input_image.size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(output_image)


# Beregne konvolusjon mellom intensity (original bilde) og  kernel 
for x in range(offset, input_image.width - offset):
    for y in range(offset, input_image.height - offset):
        acc = [0, 0, 0]
        for a in range(len(kernel)):
            for b in range(len(kernel)):
                xn = x + a - offset
                yn = y + b - offset
                pixel = input_pixels[xn, yn]
                acc[0] += pixel[0] * kernel[a][b]
                acc[1] += pixel[1] * kernel[a][b]
                acc[2] += pixel[2] * kernel[a][b]

draw.point((x, y), (int(acc[0]), int(acc[1]), int(acc[2])))

output_image.save("Beatles box blurr.png")

stop = timeit.default_timer()

print('Time: ', stop - start)
```

Comment: What didn't work? Everything in there looks like it should work in Cython so please tell us the actual error message you get

Comment: @DavidW – It did somehow run, but the running time did not decrease at all. What kind of file should the "import kandetlykkes" be? I just made a kandetlykkes.pyx - file of the code which I then copied and pasted underneath. My feeling is that it just runs the code as usual in python and hence no decrease in running time?